# Get rid of all user data of Android application after bigger update

Tags: android, google-play

I completely revamped an app. Tested it for a while on my device and emulator. The app worked fine. However when I updated the app through the Android market, my users experienced crashes.

Since there is no way to properly debug this procedure I asume the crash is caused by old data which is not being removed from the device (probably from the onsavedstate bundle?!).

Is there a way to do a "clean/total" reinstall without having the user to do it manually?

Best Regards
Johe

Comment: I'd question your assumptions. There are many subtle things that can cause crashes on different devices, particularly if you completely revamped it. Re. your old data theory, do you have any SQLite databases with your apps, store files, or use the Preferences?

Comment: If you have successfully pin pointed the error to old data then you can put code in to check if old data exists and if it does delete it. For example if you have a database then drop the tables and recreate them on installation

Comment: By taking a look at ressource files (on the device or emulator in directory /data/data/YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE/pref_files) I found that I changed one preference value from int to string, but kept the identifier... Changed that and now it works.

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the variable that's giving you trouble is overwritten with the proper type on the next OnPause, the class cast problem should be gone. You could reserve one variable to hold a version number and if the one you retrieve from OnResume is older you skip the other saved values and use the defaults.